# Why does @RequestBody not work in this SpringMVC Ajax Form Post for an Object Param?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Just curious, the following SpringMVC handler for an Ajax POST Request which submits a serialized form doesn't work and throws "Unsupported Media Type" (415).

```
@PostMapping("/myapp/add")
public boolean add(@RequestBody Person person) throws Exception { .. }
```

However, after changing `@RequestBody` to `@ModelAttribute`, it does work.

```
@PostMapping("/myapp/add")
public boolean add(@ModelAttribute Person person) throws Exception { .. }
```

I thought that `@RequestBody/@ResponseBody` were appropriate for Ajax-handling SpringMVC methods, but that `@ModelAttribute` was for regular form submission. But in this Ajax POST Request the `@ModelAttribute` works.

Ajax is called from JS as

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/myapp/add',
       data: $("#myform").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements
       dataType : "json"       
     })
     .done(function(data) {
         alert('Success!');
     });
```

There is a form which is getting serialized/submitted,

```
<form:form id="myform" .. >
   <!-- .. -->
</form:form>
```

The serialized DTO object is fully valid. It has an empty constructor, and implements Serializable, and backs all the form fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that Jquery? According to the docs: The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. So this is not JSON.

[Serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Perhaps you can try this

```
data : JSON.stringify( $(myForm).serializeArray() );
```

Comment: Yes I see now that form.serialize should be without dataType=JSON, whereas dataType=JSON requires the JSON string. thanks